# MVC Extensions Grid JQuery 1.8.2 failure

Tags: jquery, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I recently upgraded JQuery to version 1.8.2, and noticed that my MVC Extensions grid started to give me JavaScript errors when it renders empty (bound to empty data source):

I am not seeing the same error if I run JQuery 1.7.1. 
Is the MVC Extensions grid supposed to be compatible with JQuery 1.8.2?

Specifically the error seems to involve an extension of JQuery's data filter method (inside telerik.grid.min.js):

The following line inside telerik.grid.min.js causes a syntax error:
dataFilter:function(v,w){v=eval("("+v.replace(j,"new Date($1)")+")");

In my solution I have a mix of Kendo and MVC extension grids on the same page, so I need to upgrade JQuery since Kendo requires the newer version per the requirements.

Has anyone else seen this behavior?

Comment: Does thsi help you?
http://andypottsblog.blogspot.com/2012/10/telerik-mvc-extensions-and-jquery-ui.html

Comment: This looks like a different issue. My problem seems to be that the Telerik MVC extensions grid doesn't seem compatible with JQuery 1.8.2

Comment: Did you notice the piece at the end about the jQuery(false) call? That's your issue, I believe. I think Telerik is loading jQuery 1.7.1 internally. I think you need to do the jQuery(false) to prevent that. I could be wrong. I don't have Telerik to test it with. More here: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/jquery-1-8-2-failure-when-grid-renders-empty.aspx

Comment: I already have the .JQuery(false) call added since I manually add a reference to JQuery (1.8.2) in my master page. The issue is not 1.7.1, but rather that the grid doesn't seem compatible with 1.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at it in some more detail, and the cause of the error is that the grid makes an Ajax request to the server when it renders empty. I would like to prevent this behavior, but it doesn't seem like the grid offers an easy opt-out of this request. Not sure how the grid determines the route for the request, but in my case it's made to the '/' route, and the response is not compatible with the bellow code from the Telerik grid JS:

```
dataFilter:function(v,w){v=eval("("+v.replace(j,"new Date($1)")+")");
```

I made a simple sample project with a single grid and observed the same failure as in my real project.

As i mentioned earlier, the error doesn't occur when version 1.7.1 of JQuery is used.

The reason why this doesn't fail in JQuery version 1.7.1 is that the above Telerik code is executed inside a try catch block that consumes the exception. In Jquery 1.8.2 the try catch has been removed, so the error will surface in the UI.

I would really appreciate some feedback from the Telerik team about the reasoning behind this empty grid Ajax request. It seems like it could lead to a lot of side effects if the '/' route is hit every time the grid renders empty.

My current workaround is to satisfy the empty grid Ajax request, and subsequent date parsing (inside dataFilter) by returning a simple date from my action if I detect one of these requests... This will prevent the above code from throwing an exception....
Would appreciate a more seamless solution though.